# find digits occurence in an integer

Tags: c++

I guys I have a problem to create a function to count the occurrence of a number in my integers.
I create 2 int, int n which contains value from 0 to 9. Where the int value is a number that can be 1 digit up to 9 digit.
I have to create a function countOccurence to count how many times each digit occurs in the value that I put in. For example, if I type "12345", then 1 2 3 4 5 occurs once, while 6 7 8 9 0 occurs zero times. I try it but I just got stuck.

Here is what I come up so far, I just cant figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int countOccurance(int, int);
    int findDig(int);

    int value;
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
    cin >> value;
    cout << "The value is " << value << endl;

    while ((value < 0) || (value > 999999999))
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please try again!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
    }

    //process the value

}

int countOccurance(int findDig, int value)
{

}
```

thank you for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Please show us the code that got you stuck, and tell us *how* you got stuck (like what happened when you built it, what happens when you run it, for some specific input what is the expected and actual output)?

Comment: I am still thinking about it. I know how to do it without using the function. The idea that I have is separate the number individually and count how many times each number occur. But this method doesn't seems to work with the function that I have to do. This is about recursion

Comment: If using recursion, each call could check only the *last* digit in the number. A helpful tip: Boolean expression in C++ can be converted to integers, and a `true` will be `1` and `false` will always be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should give you what you're looking for.

```
int findDig(int n) 
{
    if (n < 10)
        return 1;
    else 
       return 1 + findDig(n / 10);
}

int countOccurance(int value)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        int val = value;
        int count = 0;
        while(val > 0)
        {
            if(val % 10 == i)
                count ++;
            val /= 10;
        }
        cout << count << " occourences of " << i << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int value;
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
    cin >> value;
    cout << "The value is " << value << endl;

    while ((value < 0) || (value > 999999999))
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please try again!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a positive number: " << endl;
        cin >> value //you need this here, otherwise you're going to be stuck in an infinite loop after the first invalid entry
    }

    //process the value

    cout << endl;
    cout << "This " << value << " number is a " << findDig(value) << " digit integer number." << endl;

    cout << "Digit counts" << endl;

    countOccourance(value);
}
```

*edit*

If you need countOccourence to return a value, this should do it.

```
int countOccourence(int dig, int val)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        return countOccourence(dig, val / 10) + (val % 10 == dig);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's the idea. but I don't know if this meets the requirement though. int countOccurance(int findDig,  int value). The parameter ‘findDig’  is a single digit between 0 and 9.  The parameter ‘value’ is an int of one or more digits. This recursive function returns the number of times ‘findDig’ occurs in the ‘value’.  Write a short C++ main which reads in two int values and calls this function.

Comment: I try to run it but it doenst return any value

Comment: It isn't supposed to return a value, the way I've written it. It just prints out the individual digit counts to console.